# How to get count for each month for the last 12 months

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have this query:

```
SELECT
    MONTHNAME(TIME) AS month, 
    YEAR(time) AS year, 
    COUNT(id) AS COUNT
FROM
    appointment
WHERE
    dealershipid = '38' && dealerstatus != 'No-Show' && TIME >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 12 MONTH)
GROUP BY
    MONTH(TIME)
ORDER BY
    `time` ASC
```

This is meant to return the total count of appointment records for each month over the last 12 months (rolling 12 months, not 1-12, could be Feb19-Mar20)

This is what it actually returns:

```
+-----------+------+-------+--+
|   month   | year | COUNT |  |
+-----------+------+-------+--+
| July      | 2019 |     1 |  |
| August    | 2019 |     2 |  |
| September | 2019 |     8 |  |
| October   | 2019 |     9 |  |
| November  | 2019 |    15 |  |
| December  | 2019 |     2 |  |
| January   | 2020 |     4 |  |
| February  | 2020 |     2 |  |
+-----------+------+-------+--+
```

I thought all was well and dandy, but (eg) feb 2020 actually has 13 appointments, not the stated 2.

Here is a DB fiddle with the data and the query:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pndaShANmnLZRXxNNe3GPk/1

EDIT:

Clearly the only affected one result is february (the current month), so the query's NOW() function isnt getting the entire months, rather anything before now.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions there...)

Comment: using phpmyadmin

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try `GROUP BY MONTH(TIME), YEAR(time)`.

Comment: Yeah tried that but still showing same result :(

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Just added an edit. the only issue is with feb, the current month. How do i get results from the entire of the current month, not just halfway through the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the no shows for the future appointments.  Your query filters out `NULL` values.

Try this:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(time) AS month, 
       YEAR(time) AS year, 
       COUNT(id) AS COUNT
FROM appointment
WHERE dealershipid = '38' AND
      not dealerstatus <=> 'No-Show' AND
      time >= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL (1 - DAY(CURDATE())) DAY) - INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND
      time < (CURDATE() + INTERVAL (1 - DAY(CURDATE())) DAY) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH       
GROUP BY YEAR(Time), MONTH(time)
ORDER BY MAX(time) ASC;
```

I also changed the date/time logic so it only includes complete months from a single year.  You can change it back, if you want the current month to be partial.

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5hfoV9PiZ9WPeC6VH3vab/0) is the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
dealerstatus != 'No-Show'
```

This excludes other dealer statuses **and nulls**.

You want

```
(dealerstatus != 'No-Show' OR dealerstatus IS NULL)
```

instead.

The complete corrected query:

```
SELECT
  MONTHNAME(MAX(time)) AS month,
  YEAR(time) AS year,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM appointment
WHERE dealershipid = 38
  AND (dealerstatus <> 'No-Show' OR dealerstatus IS NULL)
  AND time >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
GROUP BY YEAR(time), MONTH(time)
ORDER BY YEAR(time), MONTH(time);
```

(Your query was also invalid. I've completed the `GROUP BY` clause and added `MAX`, which would better have been `ANY_VALUE`, but your old MySQL version doesn't support it. I have also changed the date criteria, so as not to get days of last february. Don't know, whether you prefer this or not.)

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oaPmSTMuzzUDnHtMG2Jxhz/0

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This shows march 2020 aswell though? I only want up to the current month.

Comment: That wasn't evident from your own query. But, why don't you just add that condition then? (It's `AND time < LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY` in case you haven't figured that out.).